# Swift conditional conformance to both a protocol and a type

Tags: swift, protocols

I conformed an array to VectorArithmetic if it's elements are also VectorArithmetic.

```
extension Array: AdditiveArithmetic & VectorArithmetic where Element: VectorArithmetic {
static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
// etc… my implementation
}
```

I want to add a different implementation for Double array. As Double conforms to VectorArithmetic, only my above implementation is getting used. I tried:

```
extension VectorArithmetic where Self == Array<Double> {
static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
// my double implementation that gets never used.
}
```

How can I add a custom implementation for Double?

Comment: Can you post minimal code that actually compiles and demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I don't think your `+` operator is valid, it conflicts with the built-in overload which concatenates two arrays.